# What is the difference between a tap and a click?

Tags: mouse, trackpad, click, multi-touch

I can click on both my Magic Trackpad and my Magic Mouse but I can tap on neither, if my understanding is correct.

On my Magic Mouse all I can do is click. Same with Magic Trackpad.

What am I missing? I have searched web but it is hard to get relevant answers.
I am using a mid 2011 iMac with 10.11 beta but this has bothered me since Lion.
I have enabled Tap to click, but the situation is the same and my basic question is what is the difference?

Edit 2

After several reboots the trackpad now responds to tap, mouse does not.

Comment: You can enable tap to click on your Trackpad. It's in Sys Prefs > Trackpad

Comment: I have done so. I see no difference  between a tap and a click.

Comment: On the mouse that is, defective mouse?

Answer (score 4):

According to this article: [Turning On Mac Touch-To-Click Support from the Command Line](http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/31/turn-on-mac-touch-to-click-command-line/) you have to enable the feature in the command line:

Enable the general tap-to-click behavior:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool true
```

Enables tap-to-click for the Magic Mouse:

```
sudo defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
```

Enable tap-to-click at the login and boot screens of OS X:

```
sudo defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 1
```

and reboot your Mac.

To disable all this enter in Terminal:

```
sudo defaults write com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.trackpad Clicking -bool false
sudo defaults -currentHost write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 0
sudo defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.tapBehavior -int 0
```

and reboot again.